# replace \n\t from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, replace, beautifulsoup, special-characters

Hello I am using BeautifulSoup 4 and i try to replace the "\n\t" characters from the soup text.

Here is my code:

```
soup = BS(html_doc, "html.parser")
for tableItem in soup.find_all("td"):
    result = str(tableItem.string)
    result = result.replace("\n\t\", "")
    print(result)
```

This is my ouptut:

```
\n', '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTEXT_I_WANT\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
```

I tried several things with the encoding or with the beautifulsoup "NavigableString". Do I use a wrong encoding? Or are there special methods for beautifulsoup. (such like stripped_strings)

ps: I can replace TEXT_I_WANT but not "\n" or "\t"

Comment: Use string strip() method

Comment: unfortunately strip() didn't help neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:     `result = result.replace("\n\t\", "")`looks for all instances of `\n\t` then replaces them - it doesn't look for individual instances of `\n` *or* `\t`.  It seems that what you want is:

```
result = result.replace('\n', '')
result = result.replace('\t', '')
```

Comment: Hi thanks this worked for me now: result = result.replace('\\n', ' '). I needed  twice "\\" but also I had to seperated the replacement with 2 calls

Answer (score 7):

You actually need [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) instead of `string`. `get_text()` also can strip which would help you remove the `\n` and `\t` at the beginning and end of the text:

```
soup = BS(html_doc, "html.parser")
for tableItem in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(tableItem.get_text(strip=True))
```